# Can i Deploy django project without any webhost eg. heroku , pythonanywhere etc etc

Tags: django

I have created a dynamic web page using HTML5 Css3 JS And django.
I have already bought a domain name.
Now i want to deploy my django project, but dont want to use any web host like heroku aws pythonanywhere etc.

All I could find on the web is how to configure apache and mod_wsgi to serve the files.

Is it possible to create a web hosting from my home ? If yes how ?
Using ubuntu server, apache & mod_wsgi or any other technology?

P.S. I dont want to use any web hosting company

Comment: the short answer "yes"

Comment: can you please point me at the direction where i can learn how to do that ? that will be really helpful

Comment: ubuntu + nginx/apache + gunicorn + django. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/

Comment: What else do you think you need, other than "how to configure apache and mod_wsgi"? Why would that not be the information you are after?

Comment: you can also read this tutorial about how to setup the environment. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn

Comment: Also, you should really think about why you want to do this. Running your site from home means you need to think about the reliability of your internet connection, power, server availability, backups, etc... Much easier - and cheaper - to let a company do that for you.

Comment: will i be able to host without a web host using this tools ?

Comment: i want to learn how its done so its doesnt matter

Answer (score 1):

So on your local computer you have to install webserver(apache, nginx or something else).

Then you have to specify `a` note of your domain name to your home ip address(it is better when you have static IP). If you will do this, all requests that will be in to your domain name will redirect to your home IP.
Then you have to configure your webserver.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn will this help ?